# bash: find all regex in file and put into array

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a template config file with **PlaceHolders**, and i want to find all those PlaceHolders and put inside an array.

**The curent state:**
I can find all the PlaceHolders in file only if there is **no** more than **one** PlaceHolder in a **line**.

**For example**, this is my template file:

```
upstream portal {        
   server {{UNICORN_SERVICE_NAME}}:{{UNICORN_SERVICE_PORT}};  
}

server {
  listen *:80 default_server;         
  server_name {{APP_HOST}};     
  server_tokens off;     
  root /dev/null;

  # Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  # Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size {{NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE}};

  location {{GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT}}/ {
    root /var/lib/nginx/portal;
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below    
  }
  }
```

**this is the code** i use to find the PlaceHolders:

```
matches_bloc=$(awk 'match($0, /(\{\{)([^{]*)(\}\})/) {
                    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)                    
                }' ${currFile})

            # convert 'matches_bloc' into array
            matches=()
            echo "Matches:"
            while read -r line; do
                matches+=("$line")
                echo "  - ${line}"
            done <<< "$matches_bloc"
```

in this example the matches result will be:

> Matches:
>     - {{UNICORN_SERVICE_NAME}}
>     - {{APP_HOST}}
>     - {{NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE}}
>     - {{GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT}}

You can notice that there are 5 PlaceHolders in the file and only 4 matches.
The missing match is: **{{UNICORN_SERVICE_PORT}}**, because there is already another match in the same line.

**My question is:**
How can i find all the matches in the file regardless of the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find all variables in a template file and put them in an array.

With [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/):

```
array=( $(grep -Po '{{.*?}}' file) )
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="{{UNICORN_SERVICE_NAME}}" [1]="{{UNICORN_SERVICE_PORT}}" [2]="{{APP_HOST}}" [3]="{{NGINX_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE}}" [4]="{{GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT}}")'
```

> `-P`: Interpret `{{.*?}}` as a Perl regular expression.
>
> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> `*` The preceding expression can match zero or more times. With `?` the `*` tries to match as few as possible (non-greedy).

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thank you cyrus for great code, could you please explain the regex part, will be grateful to you sir.

Comment: can be done without `-P` as well... `grep -o '{{[^}]*}}' file`